# Where is the sample implementation for Google Material Design Specs

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I am looking for more than guidelines. I see a lot of details and nice screenshots here http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs

**Where is the sample implementation?** The Samples I can download from Android Studio are nowhere near as polished as the screenshots provided in the specs.

I do not mind putting up a nice big bounty on this. I have wasted 2 whole days across github, stack overflow and google to find a decent implementation of the specs which looks exactly like the specs.

Comment: I am surprised at the blocking of this question. I am not a random poster. I am on stack overflow for long time and contributed actively in GWT tag. Why block the question? I had even put up a bounty on the question because i am interested to know an answer which i cannot google for.

Comment: Did you ever find any demo projects?

Comment: Nope. The power that may at google are leaking it slowly in each new api releases. I have focused away from android and started on angular spring rest. If u find any examples post it here.

Answer (score -2):

In Android Studio Emulator, go for the "API demos" app and its sources.

Comment: Non of them implement even 1% of the Material Design "Screenshots". Please share which one you feel are implementation examples for Material Design?